# Spyder/Jupyter crashes automatically every 2 hours

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

Problem is persisting even after uninstalling an re-installing anaconda to latest versions  as of 12th Oct 2020.

Using

```
anaconda3
python 3.8
spyder 4.1.4
jupyter notebook 6.0.3.
```

Spyder automatically disappears every 2 hours irrespective of function running.

Same is case when using jupyter notebook, after every 2 hours is says

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

in the anaconda prompt.

Need help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems network related problem. Is your network board having power management enabled ?

Comment: no problems with the network. same output on a stable network. assuming it is a network connection problem, spyder is not dependent on network but even that crashes every 2 hours

Comment: Jupyter do use network to work. If connection fails, as stated in the error you provided, you cannot access it anymore. Just trying to help with the few information you gave.

Comment: Jupyter didn't seem to require an active connection to the internet. Even without internet, wifi disconnected and airplane mode on, Jupyter ran fine, imported libraries and ran functions perfectly

Comment: I am not talking about internet connection, but about your network board which may have a power management enabled it this might be an issue as it can break the connection. Jupyter is a webservice which requires network to work properly, not internet but network (they are two different things). Then Jupyter will stop to listen as a service and you will have no ability to reconnect it, thus the need to restart. Off course it is impossible to tell as we have few informations about your situation.

Comment: This message `ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` explicitly states your connection to the Jupyter service which do use the network (but not use internet) has been closed on purpose by your host (your computer). So, my first question still apply Is your network board having power management enabled ? Because the recurrent timeout of 2 hours seems a good value for it. Off course it can be something else.

Comment: @jlandercy -  'Allow computer to turn off this device to save power' is unchecked i.e. disabled under Power management tab of the network adapter.

Comment: Any other idea of process that can close connection on your network board. Antivirus? What changed since before you had the issue?

Comment: genuinely no idea. 

https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/3657

tried going through this link, disabled multiple softwares but didn't really change this.
Although, now I have switched to winPython and spyder doesn't crash anymore.